# Best practice when executing multiple queries

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, oracle

When executing multiple queries what is the best practice when using `Commands` and `DataReaders`? is it best to create only one and dispose/close it before using again or create a new one everytime and dispose/close that one? For example...

```
Dim sqlcmd as SqlCommand
Dim sqldr as SqlDatareader

sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(Query here, connection)
sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
'Do stuff
sqlcmd.Dispose()
sqldr.Close()

sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(Different Query here, connection)
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery
'Do stuff
sqlcmd.Dispose()

'And so on
```

Or

```
Dim sqlcmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Query here, connection)
Dim sqldr as SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
'Do stuff
sqlcmd.Dispose()
sqldr.Close()

Dim anothersqlcmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Different Query here, connection)
anothersqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery
'Do stuff
anothersqlcmd.Dispose()

'And so on
```

Sorry about the example, i'm aware of the `using` statement but my example is the same. Is it better to be just using 1 `Command` and `DataReader` or creating a new one everytime?

Answer (score 0):

I think regardless the allocation is there, for readability sake I would go with option two to identify when I have a new command with different parameters

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it doesn't matter. They are both the same. But in your sample 2 you have a bug by calling sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery.

I personally would put them in two separate method and call the method instead. Just make sure the connection object is open only when needed and close is right away when not needed.

Comment: Ya, sorry about that i just copy pasted and edited the first one i typed.

Comment: Speaking of connections, what issues can i run into if i open and close the connection for every command i try to execute.

Comment: @crimson589 if you just copy/pasted, then maybe you'll do the same in your code and have some problems. None, opening and closing only when needed is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: So if i had multiple queries like in my example I would only need to open at the start and close at the last query?

Answer (score 0):

This is just what I do, not necessarily Best Practices but I am very careful to close my connections and dispose of my objects.

```
cn.Open()
            If Mode = "Add" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "InsertVendor"
                RetVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            Else 'Update
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = itgID
                cmd.CommandText = "UpdateVendors"
                RetVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End If
            cn.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
```

Here, I used one command object but tailored it for 2 different operations. To get everything cleaned up I use Try..Catch..Finally

```
Finally
            If Not IsNothing(cmd) Then
                cmd.Dispose()
            End If
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn.Close()
            End If
        End Try
```

Then check on the state of my objects there. There should never be an exception in a Finally block. I do use the same connection object throughout my DataAccess Class. Be careful of the DataReader; don't close your connection until it has finished its work.